# MySQL Fire Trigger for both Insert and Update

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is it possible to fire a mysql trigger for both the insert and update events of a table?

I know I can do the following

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON `table`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
.....
END //

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
    AFTER UPDATE ON `table`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
.....
END //
```

But how can I do

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON `table` AND
    AFTER UPDATE ON `table`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
.....
```

Is it possible, or do I have to use 2 triggers? The code is the same for both and I don't want to repeat it.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You have to create two triggers, but you can move the common code into a procedure and have them both call the procedure.

Comment: Could you give a toy example of this for those of us who are unfamiliar with the syntax?

Comment: @Zxaos: I'd suggest starting with http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html (which includes some examples) and asking your own question(s) if needed.

Comment: "strongly recommend not calling any stored procedures from a Trigger"
# https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10657/call-a-stored-procedure-from-a-trigger

Comment: @luismartingil there is probably some extra overhead of calling a procedure vs. inlining it. But in exchange you get easier maintenance and a guarantee that the two triggers' code won't accidentally diverge.

Answer (score 60):

In response to @Zxaos request, since we can not have AND/OR operators for MySQL triggers, starting with your code, below is a complete example to achieve the same.

**1. Define the INSERT trigger:**

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS my_insert_trigger//
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost TRIGGER my_insert_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON `table`
    FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    -- Call the common procedure ran if there is an INSERT or UPDATE on `table`
    -- NEW.id is an example parameter passed to the procedure but is not required
    -- if you do not need to pass anything to your procedure.
    CALL procedure_to_run_processes_due_to_changes_on_table(NEW.id);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

**2. Define the UPDATE trigger**

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS my_update_trigger//

CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost TRIGGER my_update_trigger
    AFTER UPDATE ON `table`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- Call the common procedure ran if there is an INSERT or UPDATE on `table`
    CALL procedure_to_run_processes_due_to_changes_on_table(NEW.id);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

**3. Define the common PROCEDURE used by both these triggers:**

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure_to_run_processes_due_to_changes_on_table//

CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE procedure_to_run_processes_due_to_changes_on_table(IN table_row_id VARCHAR(255))
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

    -- Write your MySQL code to perform when a `table` row is inserted or updated here

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

You note that I take care to restore the delimiter when I am done with my business defining the triggers and procedure.

Comment: What's `IN table_row_id VARCHAR(255)` in this case? I mean how are you defining which row is going to be inserted or updated?

Comment: Is there a reason you left in the begin / end statements in the triggers, since each trigger now executes only a single statement?

Comment: @VaTo the table_row_id is the way you know which row in the table was added or updated.

Comment: @ucbpaladin the // are left to ease reuse of the code if more stuff is added in the triggers.

Answer (score 14):

unfortunately we can't use in MySQL **after INSERT or UPDATE** description, like in Oracle