# MySQL MD5(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) On Update

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a user registration form and when I get to confirming the user's email by emailing them, I need some sort of unique string to confirm against.

Instead of generating one in PHP and inserting it into the database, I wanted to try and add a column to my table that would hold a unique value that I could use whenever I needed to confirm something.

What I want to do is set the value to an MD5 of the current timestamp. I tried just doing `SELECT MD5(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` in phpMyAdmin just to see if it would let me and it did so I thought I'd add that to an update condition but it doesn't seem to be letting me.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD confirmation VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE MD5(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

The above is what I've tried. I get an error and I don't know how else to do it.

Is there anyway I can do this or something similar? Side question, does the `ON UPDATE` trigger on a row that just got inserted?

Comment: You can not do that, default value should be constant. Take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270309/can-i-use-a-function-for-a-default-value-in-mysql, you might consider to create a function and trigger for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you are trying to use doesn't exist. It looks like you are thinking of `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` but that is a rather specific command, as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

> Use of DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is
>   specific to TIMESTAMP.

So the `ON UPDATE` clause only works with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and only on fields of type `TIMESTAMP`.

If you want to use the MD5 of the current timestamp either set a trigger, or just manually set the value (e.g. `UPDATE users SET confirmation=MD5(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) WHERE user_id=123`).

Bare in mind that the MD5 of the current timestamp is something that could be quite easily guessed / brute forced, so don't rely on it for security.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to create a single trigger for both `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s?

Comment: @Spedwards Not possible in MySQL, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318224/mysql-fire-trigger-for-both-insert-and-update for more details. Think twice before using triggers - they can be useful and the most appropriate method, but equally can be dangerous and lead to lots of problems down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Use a universal unique identifier for this purpose. It's a 128-bit unique number; it's designed for this kind of thing.

It has a string representation that fits in 36 bytes.

```
 aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee
```

You can generate these things in most programming languages. In MySQL you use the [UUID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function to get one. Every time you call UUID(), you're guaranteed to get a new value.

Add a CHAR(36) column to your database, or just use your VARCHAR(40) column.

You can't use data definition language (ALTER TABLE) to declare ON UPDATE except for a native timestamp. You'll need application code to set your UUID values, just like you do for MD5(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

Comment: `Every time you call UUID(), you're guaranteed to get a new value.` Probably being a bit pedantic here, but this isn't true. The intention is that each UUID is unique, but there is no guarantee.