# How to separate DELETE, UPDATE and INSERT operations within a MySQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, plsql, triggers

I have the following trigger in Oracle database -

```
CREATE TRIGGER B4DEL
BEFORE DELETE ON test FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF deleting THEN
        INSERT INTO tab VALUES (:old.oid,'Deleting');
    END IF;
    IF inserting THEN
        INSERT INTO tab VALUES (:new.oid,'Inserting');
    END IF;
END;
```

I want to do something similar in MySQL database by using a single trigger.

Comment: we can't use in MySQL after INSERT or UPDATE description, like in Oracle . read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318224/mysql-fire-trigger-for-both-insert-and-update

Comment: Thanks, I am getting it, but what I want is to differentiate the statements based upon operations within the trigger, simply an alternative to - IF **deleting** THEN ..... END IF; IF **inserting** THEN ....; END IF; part. How to figure out what operation is being performed within the trigger definition.