# Mysql trigger on update or insert on any table of database

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I have a trigger to check any insert or update on whole database?

I tried this but it didn't work:

create trigger updateHistory after insert on database

Comment: "Can I have a trigger to check any insert or update on whole database' - no you cannot, triggers are on a per table basis.

Answer (score 0):

Yaou need to elaborate the `database` into separate tables. And give the action. Eg:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER updatehistory
    BEFORE UPDATE ON `table,table2`
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
    SET action = 'insert',
     record = OLD.record,
        changedat = NOW(); 
END
```

And as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318231/6274120),  you cannot create both `insert` and `update` at the same trigger, but you can move the common code into a procedure and have them both call the procedure.