# SQL lookup like function

Tags: mysql

I have 5 columns in SQL table

```
Id  | activity    | start date | Finish date | Predecessor activity 
1   | shuttering  | 1/1/2019   | 3/1/2019    | 
2   | concrete    |            | 6/1/2019    | 1
```

The above is an example of my table
I need to plan my activities and all the activities are interlinked
The ID 2 succeeds activity 1
So start date of ID 2 is finish date of 1
I need all the start dates to be auto generated except first one based on predecessor activity

Comment: What have you tried so far? What where the problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this table

```
CREATE TABLE Schedule1
(`Id` int, `activity` varchar(10), `start_date` datetime
, `Finish_date` datetime, `Predecessor_activity` int)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO Schedule1
(`Id`, `activity`, `start_date`, `Finish_date`, `Predecessor_activity`)
VALUES
(1, 'shuttering', '2019-01-01', '2019-03-01 01:00:00', NULL),
(2, 'concrete', NULL, '2019-06-01 02:00:00', 1),
(3, 'concrete', NULL, '2019-08-01 02:00:00', 2),
(4, 'concrete', NULL, '2019-10-01 02:00:00', 3);
```

This sql statemenbt

```
UPDATE Schedule1 t2
Left JOIN Schedule1 t1 ON t2.Predecessor_activity   = t1.Id
SET t2.start_date = IFNULL(t2.start_date,t1.Finish_date);
```

gets you

```
Id  activity    start_date              Finish_date          Predecessor_activity
1   shuttering  2019-01-01 00:00:00     2019-03-01 01:00:00     
2   concrete    2019-03-01 01:00:00     2019-06-01 02:00:00     1
3   concrete    2019-06-01 02:00:00     2019-08-01 02:00:00     2
4   concrete    2019-08-01 02:00:00     2019-10-01 02:00:00     3
```

for the use of trigger like insert or update
like this

```
#DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS my_update_trigger;
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost TRIGGER my_update_trigger
AFTER update ON `schedule1`
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
-- Call the common procedure ran if there is an INSERT or UPDATE on `table`
-- NEW.id is an example parameter passed to the procedure but is not required
-- if you do not need to pass anything to your procedure.
CALL procedure_to_run_schedule()//
END//
```

DELIMITER ;

We nee a new Table, because updating the same table isn't allowed for triggers.
So we create a new table that is identical to our original

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS newschedul;

CREATE TABLE newschedule SElect * From Schedule1;
```

And then we add a new stored procedure.
What it does, After you inserted or updated your original table, it copies all data to the new table and uses above statement to make the new schedule.
so you can access the actual schedule by selecting rows from the. Updfating and isnert you only make in the schedule to avoid the problmes you described

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure_to_run_schedule//

CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE procedure_to_run_schedule()
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

  SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
   DELETE FROM newschedule;
   INSERT INTO newschedule
     SELECT * FROM Schedule1;
    UPDATE newschedule t2
    Left JOIN newschedule t1 ON t2.Predecessor_activity   = t1.Id
   SET t2.start_date = IFNULL(t2.start_date,t1.Finish_date) ;
  SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
END//
DELIMITER
```

Comment: instead of `IFNULL()` is better use a condition  `WHERE t2.start_date IS NOT NULL` so if you have an index doesnt have to do a full table scan

Comment: If tried that before i used IFNULL, but i doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you .But i have a small problem.I nedd the coloumn to be updated automatically.But the above code doesnt automatically do that.I have to run the query evertime to update values.

Comment: Hi, ou have to build a trigger onupdate and iinsert  like here shown https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318224/mysql-fire-trigger-for-both-insert-and-update.

Comment: Hi I tried creating a trigger .but after creating a trigger I can't insert values Into table as it shows an error "can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement "